# Programatic property injection with Microsoft Unity

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container, property-injection

I use contructor injection in my solution, but this one class has a property that i do not want to pass in the constructor where i have the invariant dependencies.

Let's say i got an ILogger and it has a FileName property i want to set, while still having it set the dependancies in the contructor.
How do i go about registering the type, and at the same time pass the defaunt connection string.

I hope there is an easy way to do it - preferably without decorating the property with an attribute, but if the setup is easier with the attribute i guess that's cool :)

So the question is, how do i inject a property value on an object that also uses contructor injection - with Unity.

UPDATE: I mentioned it in the title, but i forgot to elaborate in the body of the text - i want to set these dependencies up manually (in code) as opposed to in a config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i guess it helped to ask the question, i found out - here it is.

```
container.Configure<InjectedMembers>().ConfigureInjectionFor<BasicLogger>(
  new InjectionProperty("FileName", @"C:\test.log")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are injecting properties you have to use [Dependency] or else manually inject that dependency.

Comment: Yeah i didn't make it very clear - but i do want to do it manually ;)

Answer (score 0):

You usually want an IConfiguration interface to be injected. This would probably have a LogFile property that you can read.

The Configuration implimentation is usually just a simple wrapper to read items from the config file.

Comment: You got a good point there, but we're trying to keep it as simple as possible, and all this specific implementation needs is a filename.